# How can I set data-content on hr:after in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know you can add style to an element in javascript. E.g.

```
myElement.style.color = "red";
```

But say I wanted to do the equivalent of

```
hr:after {
  content: "myRuntimeValue"
}
```

How can I achieve that in javascript?

Comment: You can't style pseudo elements via JavaScript

Comment: So it's not possible? (At least I know what to google now - thx)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this indirectly via element attribute:

CSS

```
p#my-id::after {
    // set content to be the value of an attribute on the element p
    content: attr(data-value);
}
```

JS

```
const element = document.getElementById('my-id');
element.setAttribute('data-value', 'myRuntimeValue');
```

Answer (score 1):

`:before` and `:after` are not actual DOM-elements... so, you can't do anything with them from JS.

But you can create two classes, with different contents and styles, and toggle the class:

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/5ewc3kag/)

```js
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.remove('demo');
  this.classList.add('New-demo');
});
```

```css
.demo:after {
  content: " myRuntimeValue";
  color: orange;
}
.New-demo:after {
  content: " Some New Bubu!";
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" class="demo">Click Me!</p>
```

With this trick, you can not only change the content, but add actual styles.